# javascript countdown timer new date

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using javascript for a count down timer

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
        var newYear = $(".HF").val();
            alert('hehe' + newYear);
            $('#countdown').countdown({ until:newYear, format: 'DHMS', layout:
'<div id="timer">' + '<hr />' +
    '<div id="timer_days" class="timer_numbers">{dnn}</div>' +
    '<div id="timer_hours" class="timer_numbers">{hnn}</div>' +
    '<div id="timer_mins" class="timer_numbers">{mnn}</div>' +
    '<div id="timer_seconds" class="timer_numbers">{snn}</div>' +
'<div id="timer_labels">' +
    '<div id="timer_days_label" class="timer_labels">days</div>' +
    '<div id="timer_hours_label" class="timer_labels">hours</div>' +
    '<div id="timer_mins_label" class="timer_labels">mins</div>' +
    '<div id="timer_seconds_label" class="timer_labels">secs</div>' +
'</div>' +
'</div>'
            });
        });
</script>
```

it gets its until value from a hidden field `HF`.The value of the hidden field is a string 10/22/2011...but the timer shows only 34 mins left while it must show 2 days and some hours and some mins left..why??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `newYear` string has to be converted to a `Date` object:

```
var newYear = $(".HF").val();
newYear = new Date(newYear); // 10/22/2011 > Dat object of 22 Okt 2011
```